# How accurate is `st_mtime_ns`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system

The [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat_result.st_mtime_ns) say

> **Note:** The exact meaning and resolution of the st_atime, st_mtime, and st_ctime attributes depend on the operating system and the file system. For example, on Windows systems using the FAT or FAT32 file systems, st_mtime has 2-second resolution, and st_atime has only 1-day resolution.

However, they go on to imply that `st_mtime_ns` has significantly higher resolution:

> Similarly, although st_atime_ns, st_mtime_ns, and st_ctime_ns are always expressed in nanoseconds, many systems do not provide nanosecond precision. On systems that do provide nanosecond precision, the floating-point object used to store st_atime, st_mtime, and st_ctime cannot preserve all of it, and as such will be slightly inexact. If you need the exact timestamps you should always use st_atime_ns, st_mtime_ns, and st_ctime_ns.

What is the resolution of `st_mtime_ns`?

(X for Y: I need to check if a file has changed since I last ran my program.  This means I need to wait until the file's timestamp is at least (resolution) seconds in the past before recording it, so I can detect if it was modified immediately after I looked at it)

Comment: As the docs say, the resolution is OS and filesystem-dependent, and you haven't provided details of either. So the best answer any of us can offer you is *it depends*. Even though `st_mtime_ns` may be *expressed* in nanoseconds, the *actual* resolution can't be any more accurate than the system that reports it. So on FAT32 you will get the time correct to within 2,000,000,000 nanoseconds.

Comment: @BoarGules Yes it depends, but that doesn't mean "it depends" is the best answer you can give.  Is there a function which tells me what the resolution is?  For example, is there a value I can pass to `time.get_clock_res(...)` which will tell me how accurate `st_mtime_ns` is?  Is there a common library which provides this functionality?  Etc.

Comment: No, not that I know of. Such a function would have be based on an OS system call. On this subject, the MS documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfiletime says no more than *it depends*. For MacOS or Posix, I've no idea, but I doubt it.

Comment: Well ... damn.  That sucks.  I guess I'll just have to pick a decent default value and rely on the user to get it right if they need to change it.  Probably 10s will do for most systems.  Thanks for your help!